# The convergence of a product of sequences converging in $L^2$.

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Earlier today I found myself pondering the following question for which I do not have a reasonable answer.

> Suppose $f_m\to f$ and $g_m\to g$ in $L^2$. Moreover suppose that $f_m g_m\in L^2$ for all $m$ and $fg\in L^2$. Is it the case that $f_m g_m \to fg$ in $L^2$?

The naive approach of using a clever form of $0$ doesn't quite work since you get

$$\|fg - f_mg_m\| \le \|(f-f_m)g\| + \|f_m(g-g_m)\|.$$

The simplest way to ensure that this goes to zero is if you have an $L^{\infty}$ uniform boundedness on the $f_m$ and an $L^{\infty}$ boundedness on $g$. The latter condition is not overly strong, but the $L^{\infty}$ uniform boundedness of the $f_m$ is a very strong condition. Moreover, implicit in this approach is the slightly hidden assumption that $f_mg \in L^2$ for all $m$. I also thought about extracting pointwise almost everywhere convergent subsequences but I got my wires crossed.

If this is not true in general, what conditions can be placed to ensure this holds? Conditions than those stated above, of course, since those conditions are very strong.

Comment: If the theorem were true, take $f=g$. If $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$ and $f_n^2,f \in L^2$, then do you have $f_n^2 \to f^2$ in $L^2$? Assuming $f_n \to f$ a.s. as well (take a subsequence if you must), this is equivalent to $f_n \to f$ in $L^4$. That certainly doesn't seem right...

Comment: The $L^4$ convergence seemed to be what I was circling around, but I was doubting myself on that front. I was considering that an $L^4$ convergence was necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f_n$ be a square function with width $1/n$ and height $\sqrt{n}$. Then $f_n\rightarrow 0$ in $L^2$. Let $g_n=f_n$...

Comment: This is a pretty good counterexample. I should have thought about reducing to the case of $f_n = g_n$. Coming up with separate sequences was becoming pretty painful. D'oh.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: sorry, we don't need it to be sliding, which takes care of the finite measure case as well.

Comment: Very true! It doesn't seem to be easily rectified. Oh well. This spurred from a consideration of the Fourier convolution theorem on $L^2$ (or its appropriate statement there, anyway). I was hoping to avoid the $L^1$ theory of the Fourier transform and stay within the realm of the $L^2$ theory but it seems not to be possible.